# ROS2 MoveIt can't find mimic joint

Tags: ros2, moveit

In ROS2 Humble, I'm attempting to add a rudimentary gripper to a UR arm, simulate in Gazebo (fortress), and control using MoveIt. I'm starting from the official UR URDF and MoveIt config files, and somewhat haphazardly trying to combine them with my gripper URDF and modified configs. Currently when I run the system, I'm getting the repeated error:

`[move_group-6] [ERROR] [1691647994.590613776] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Joint 'left_finger_joint_mimic' not found in model 'mybot'`

The gripper URDF has a mimic joint named `left_finger_joint`, which is also added to a group in my SRDF:

```
<group name="${prefix}gripper">
  <link name="${prefix}palm" />
  <link name="${prefix}finger_left" />
  <link name="${prefix}finger_right" />
  <joint name="${prefix}right_finger_joint" />
  <passive_joint name="${prefix}left_finger_joint" />
</group>
```

However, it appears ros2_control is appending `_mimic` to the controller (confirmed by calling `/controller_manager/list_controllers`), which is then confusing MoveIt. (Edit: it is happening in `gz_ros2_control`: https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control/blob/cf5c6a4135d6b46c95e0e135ffd0400fb4db7731/ign_ros2_control/src/ign_system.cpp#L279)

Am I supposed to explicitly refer to `left_finger_joint_mimic` somewhere in the SRDF, or elsewhere? I'm particularly confused because I've been referring to https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/tree/humble/panda_moveit_config, which similarly has a mimic joint, but doesn't seem to ever refer to it with `_mimic` appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Gazebo ROS2 Control plugin issue and the same issue exists in Gazebo Classic implementation of gazebo_ros2_control as documented in [this issue](https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/issues/173). I also stumbled across the same [Ign Gazebo issue you seem to have found here (for reference)](https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control/issues/96)
The plugin adds a (as far as I'm aware unused) mimic suffix to mimic joints when parsing the URDF, creating a hardware interface with the suffixed version of the joint name. The intent is to semantically signify that the joints are not actually controlled / measured, but this unsurprisingly confuses Moveit, because the URDF references hardware with a different name than what the `ros2_control` hardware manager lists.

In that case, as will likely be the case for "Ignition" Gazebo, simply removing the suffix or changing it to an empty string should fix your issues with Moveit without breaking anything.

If you are unable to build the Gazebo ros2_control plugins from source, you can modify the generated URDF used by Moveit to reference the mimic joint, but I don't personally encourage that approach.

EDIT: responding to [this comment](https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control/issues/96#issuecomment-1328196494)

First, `robot_state_publisher`:
My understanding is that `robot_state_publisher` couldn't care less whether a joint has a `_mimic` suffix in the name or not. [It just looks for any joint that has the `<mimic>` element set and adds that to a set of `mimic_` joints](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/blob/9a50d7897d6437a63af1d9f8e602240105b35b2d/src/robot_state_publisher.cpp#L185-L191). [When evaluating the state for the joints in the `mimic_` set, the `robot_state_publisher` will *override* state in the `JointState` msg it receives](https://%20https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/blob/9a50d7897d6437a63af1d9f8e602240105b35b2d/src/robot_state_publisher.cpp#L342-L348).

Now this *might* cause unexpected behavior if you also have your `JointStateBroadcaster` setup to publish joint states for your mimic joint (as would be the default behavior when no joints are specified), as you'd have a separate node overriding the data getting published by `ros2_control`. But also, I'd argue it doesn't really matter if the `JointStateBroadcaster` is publishing state information that is getting ignored, since (in a perfect world) both `ros2_control` and `robot_state_publisher` should have the same understanding of the mimic's joint state and the math to get the mimics state from the parent is fairly trivial. Again, this *might* cause issues if the Gazebo simulation is acting strangely and the mimic isn't following its parent as one might expect *and* you're assuming the published joint state for a mimic joint will have perfect omniscient state knowledge that exactly matches the sim (rather than the implied state information from the mimic relationship). It sounds like @destogl was interested in that "perfect" state information for debugging purposes, but it seems like an uncommon use case to me, and you could extract the same information by subscribing to the `/joint_states` topic anyways.

For `RViz`, my understanding of any typical use cases that might involve joint states (visualizing TFs, Robot Models, etc), is that RViz again doesn't care what the name of a joint is or whether its a mimic. To my knowledge it uses the transforms published by `robot_state_publisher`, so as long as those are consistent, I don't foresee (or remember from when I tried this workaround ~1/2 a year ago) any `RViz` issues. I'm not aware of any `RViz` functionality that would break, but that's not to say they don't exist.

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control/issues/96#issuecomment-1328196494), it seems like simply dropping `_mimic` may have some consequences?

Comment: I'll update my answer to respond